# Getting error while opening /etc/profile: Error reading lock file /etc/.profile.swp: Not enough data read

Tags: nano

I am getting this error while opening `/etc/profile` file using nano.

```
Error reading lock file /etc/.profile.swp: Not enough data read
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: which version of nano are you using? Please type `nano --version`

Comment: This might be part of a known (and now resolved) bug in `nano` - do other text editors work with this file? You may need to upgrade your `nano` version to resolve depending on a the results of a `nano --version`.

Comment: my nano version is 2.5.3

Comment: Interesting. Can you run the following to see what/who else is accessing the swap file, and copy the output here please? - `vi /etc/.profile.swp`.

Comment: This swap file is only access by me to set the paths of java, hive, hadoop, pig etc. I'm able to open  and edit the file using gedit, but not with nano.

Answer (score 58):

Try to remove the hidden file `.[yourfilename].swp`, which is stored in the same folder as the file that you are trying to open.
In your case try the shell command `rm /etc/.profile.swp`.

This issue also occurs with nano 2.7.4, and must be something to do with how nano handles a corrupted swapfile.

Hope this helped

Comment: Use `ls -a` to see the hidden file as `.[your_file].swp`, next, try to remove it. Worked!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is linked to a bug in an older version of `nano` as seen [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nano/+bug/1539627).

As per the report, the affected version was `nano-2.4.2`. You should run `nano --version` to ascertain your current version and update accordingly.

A more detailed report of the actual issue can be found [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=787914).

Comment: My nano version is 2.5.3

Comment: My nano version is 2.9.3 and the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Was happening for me because I was out of disk space, I cleared up some space, deleted the swap file and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this one (run this on the current folder):

```
find . -name "*.swp" -delete
```

Keep in mind that as [@pbhj commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939527/getting-error-while-opening-etc-profile-error-reading-lock-file-etc-profile/1427962#comment2498593_1427962):

> [...] this will find all files below the current root, ending in .swp, and delete them. Which should work to remove temporary nano files, but might have unintended consequences.

Comment: @TejasLotlikar I faced this same issue, and it got resolved by running this command.

Comment: I mean, this will find all files below the current root, ending in .swp, and delete them. Which should work to remove temporary nano files, but might have unintended consequences. Not the highest quality answer, but a working answer to the question nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

This happened for me because of a log file that wasn't rotating, it took the entire disk space, I solved it by truncating this log file, then removing the .swp file.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was because of running docker container logs.
Worked fine after deleting them.
Logs location: `/var/lib/docker/containers/`
`rm -rf /var/lib/docker/containers/*`

Note: this will delete all the log generated till today, you may choose to deleted not required and also take backup to avoid logs data loss.